# Integrating MySQL + Webserver + PHP in Java Application

Tags: java, php, webserver, xampp, desktop-application

What's the best way to integrate a MySQL Database (no SQLite) and a Webserver like Apache with  PHP functionality into a Java Desktop Application? I need to be able to access the Database from Java and the webserver via a webbrowser, PHP is querying the same MYSQL Database as Java. I thought of somehow packaging XAMPP in the Application Installer and then call the specific start batch files from Java but that seems to be kind of a hackish way to me. How is something like this typically done?

Thanks in advance,

Stefan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace Apache with [Jetty](http://jetty.codehaus.org/jetty/) which is an embeddable web server built with java. Jetty can serve php pages if it's linked to the php executable.  MySQL is not a great option for this at all - if you need a portable high powered solution use MongoDB which you can simply package and run alongside your application.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit strange idea. However could be a solution if you construct an installer solution. For example: http://www.advancedinstaller.com/java.html